# PHP no permission to write to file in MAC

Tags: php, macos, permission-denied, jpgraph

I am using XAMPP(PHP APACHE MYSQL) to develop a program in MAC. When I try to use JPGRAPH to write to file, code:
`$fileName = "/img/bar.png";
$graph->img->Stream($fileName);`
I got this warning: Cant write to file, check that the process running PHP has enough permission.
I searched a lot, and tried many ways: 1.sudo chmod 777 ~/File/Java/img 2.change user name in Apache httpd.conf (default username is nobody) 3.mkdir($create_path, 0777). Still I cant figure it out. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the image directory outside the project directory?

Comment: img directory is under the project dir

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the / at the start of /img/bar.png

Comment: Agreed.  You are attempting to write relative to the root of the boot disk, not relative to your application.

Comment: Yep, you could also just prepend a . to your path like so ./img/bar.png

Comment: Just tried removing the /, but still got the same warning msg.

Comment: could you post your file hierarchy starting at the root of your application, and tell us which file this code is in?

Comment: the code is in the file named barshow.php, path: ~/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Twitter/barshow.php.  Twitter dir is the project dir. img dir is also in the Twitter dir: .../Twitter/img

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 
   $root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/img";
   $fileName = "$root/bar.png";
```

Hope this helps.